# Robosuite - Building Your Own Environment

Tags: xml, environment, robotics, mujoco

[robosuite](https://github.com/ARISE-Initiative/robosuite): A Modular Simulation Framework and Benchmark for Robot Learning. I am trying to build my own environment in the robosuite/docs/quickstart.md #BYOE. I have followed the steps in order and when I print the model, I get the message: <mujoco._structs.MjModel object at 0x7f163da2bef0>.
[Build your own environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdhiB.png)

I have tried loading an xml file that I read from the [Overview first example with hello.xml and C++ example that runs the data.](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html). I was hoping for it to work and open a separate window with a simulation.